# Is there a data race if pthread_cond_signal is the last call in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, posix

Compiling this with `-fsanitize=thread` yields a data race report between `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_cond_destroy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <err.h>

bool done = false;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;

void *func(void *)
{   
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    done = true;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;

    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, NULL) != 0)
        err(1, "pthread_create()");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    while (!done)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The report goes away if I call `pthread_mutex_unlock` after `pthread_cond_signal`. But the manual says `pthread_cond_signal` doesn't need the mutex to be taken. Is it documented anywhere that calling `pthread_cond_signal` as the last call that references a `pthread_cond_t`, and destroying it from the thread that does `pthread_cond_wait` is not legal ?

Comment: Use std::thread in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it documented anywhere that calling pthread_cond_signal as the last call that references a pthread_cond_t, and destroying it from the thread that does pthread_cond_wait is not legal ?

They cannot cover all corner cases in documentation. Yes it is legal to call `pthread_cond_signal()` after mutex unlocked, it is not legal to destroy it at the same time as `pthread_cond_signal()` can be called.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to destroy the condition variable and the mutex before joining the thread that may still use it. Consider this scenario:

1. Main creates the thread and is interrupted.
2. `func()` runs until the `pthread_mutex_unlock`, but is interrupted before it signals.
3. `main` continues, `done` is true, so it never waits, unlocks the mutex and destroys the condition variable, then waits for the thread to exit.
4. `func()` calls `pthread_cond_signal` on the destroyed condition variable - probably a bad idea.

Fix:

Move the join before the two "destroys".

In your example I think holding the mutex longer would prevent this, but I think it is not a sustainable approach for larger software.

I would not recommend to destroy any synchronization objects (mutex, condition, etc.) before it is absolutely obvious, that all threads that are supposed to use them are joined or are guaranteed by other explicit synchronization to never access the synchronization objects again.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally legal to call `pthread_cond_signal` as the last call.
And it is also not needed to hold a mutex for the the `pthread_cond_signal`.
But in your case if you do not do this it is possible that you create a data race. This is illegal.
In your case it is possible that when your thread unlocks the mutex your main thread starts to run and destroys the condition. This is your data race.

So you have two possibilities.
Either you hold the mutex when calling `pthread_cond_signal` so that your main thread cannot access the condition before it is used.
Or you can first join your thread and then destroy the condition. Both will work.

But in general i recommend to stick to `std::thread`, `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`